# ListIterator solution without using previous

Tags: java, list, linked-list, listiterator

Lets say we have this code :

```
LinkedList<Integer> myIntegers  = new LinkedList<Integer>();
ListIterator<Integer> myIntegersIt = myIntegers.listIterator    

myIntegers.add(1);
myIntegers.add(2);
myIntegers.add(3);
myIntegers.add(4);
myIntegers.add(5);

LinkedList<Integer> selectedValues = new LinkedList<Integer>();

while(myIntegersIt.hasNext()){

  if(...some code...){
    selectedValues.add(myIntegersIt.next());
  }
  myIntegers.remove(myIntegersIt.previous());
}
```

Is there any alternative solution without using previous?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What's wrong with `Iterator.remove`?

Comment: What's your program supposed to do? As it is your code could easily throw an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**myIntegers** list can be browse with enhanced for...
no iterator needed

```
    for (Integer integer : myIntegers) {
        if(...some code...){
            selectedValues.add(myIntegersIt.next());
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to remove all the data from the list anyway, if you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), this is an easy operation.

Stream over your array, filter the wanted values with a logic condition and return it in the form of a `List`

```
selectedValues = myIntegers.stream().filter(x -> /*sometest*/).collect(Collectors.toList());
myIntegers.clear();
```

---

Using `List#removeIf(Predicate)` is also a nice way to do it.

```
myIntegers.removeIf(x -> //testToRemove);
selectedValues = new LinkedList<>(myIntegers);
myIntegers.clear();
```